# Every second person is gay now! How would that affect earth's population?

Tags: science-based, population

The villain of my (comedic) story is basically a gay Thanos, turning half of earth's population gay with a simple finger snap. Just like regular Thanos, he is concerned with the dwindling resources vs high population problem, so he hopes turning every second person gay would fix it, as the gay population can't really procreate (duh).

How would that affect earth, specifically humans? How much would that reduce the overall population? Would it cripple humanity too much?

Comment: What's to stop the other half from doubling their output to compensate?

Comment: Does 'The Snap' also change the mindset, e.g. the turned people are okay with now being gay?

Comment: Homosexual men are perfectly able to have sex with women. Homosexual women can get pregnant just like hererosexual women. So it's not a problem; people will have procreative sex although they don't like it very much, just as today people work for money although they'd rather drink beer on the beach.

Comment: When statistics say that 10% of people somewhere are gay, what they actually mean is that 10% of the people have come out. 50% worldwide? We might not even notice.

Comment: And for the record, the idea that more people being gay would cripple humanity is bigotry. More or less people with various sexualities does not impact on any society's birth rates.

Comment: @nzaman Why would the other half even want to compensate? If I want a child, I won't make two just to compensate for my gay neighbours.

Comment: How gay is the villain making them?  Straight/Gay is a spectrum not a binary.

Comment: Please see [How to deal with “Please develop my High Concept” questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/809) on meta. Also, this question fails a book test: it is quite easy to imagine a book written on this topic (actually, The Forever War was in huge part about such idea, for example), and that usually means question is too broad and opinion based.

Comment: I think this question is answerable, even though people in the comments and even the answers tend to focus on certain aspects of it that do not really matter, but you should definitely limit the scope. The world is a large place with many different cultures and subcultures. Future population development is a complicated topic, if you introduce restrictions like that, well, the result can be anything and should be very different locally. It also really matters what time spans you are looking at. Are new kids born also 50% only interested in the same sex?

Comment: @Raditz_35 "on certain aspects of it that do not really matter" - these aspects do not really matter *for you*, but these aspects are not out of scope now. Also, the issue with gay<->straight being non-binary is quite serious, because it is purely an opinion where the border is and should you really count 'bi' between as separate group.

Comment: I don't really think this question is "opinion based" - It could conceivably be answered with simple maths - ok there are a lot of other things to consider that may introduce variables (e.g. governments may offer incentives to have more kids to compensate, etc.) but that is no different from most questions on here, but it can certainly be answered, even if it's with caveats / qualifications

Comment: @ArcanistLupus - Your point is taken, but I'd say the implication of the question is that the gay people don't like sex with the opposite gender.

Comment: FYI: in the past it was common for homosexuals to get married so that they could get a social alibi and then cultivate their true passion in a more discreet way. And often from those marriages kids were born.

Comment: I don't think the question is "opinion based" - every aspect of it can be properly argued. I do however think that it's too broad, because there are just too many of those aspects.

Comment: @Liquid:[Le Chatelier's Principle](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Equilibria/Le_Chatelier%27s_Principle)--it's not just chemistry

Answer (score 4):

### What is going to fall is the rate of unintended pregnancies:

> *How many pregnancies are unplanned in the US?*
>   An unintended pregnancy is one that was either mistimed or unwanted (45% of all pregnancies). [Unintended Pregnancy in the United States](https://www.guttmacher.org/fact-sheet/unintended-pregnancy-united-states)

Since half the population is now gay, recreational sex is less likely to trigger an accidental pregnancy. If we take that rateo as accurate world-wide, we can maybe expect it to halve down, or at least lose a 10%.

This wouldn't do anything for wanted pregnancies, thought. Since being gay doesn't do anything to your parental instincts, people would still **want** children at some time in their lives.

Answer (score 1):

News flash: conceiving a child doesn't nessecary involve a man and a woman having sex anymore!

Gay men can donate as much sperm as heterosexual men. You don't even need artificial fertilization to create a fetus from a sperm donation, it could be applied directly into the uterus of the woman (as is done in industrial livestock breeding). Maybe the number of artificial fertilizations would increase (because the sucess rates are much higher), but it would not cripple the human population beyond repair.

Another thought: Even gay men *can* have sex with women. Depending on how much the culture changed by this event, it could be seen as another type of sperm donation. There have even been gay transgender men who gave birth to children. 
*Side note: This raises the interesting question of who counts as "man" and would be affected by the villainy finger-snip...*

If the effect of the villainy finger snipping isn't inherited by the next generation, you would have a temporary cultural adaptation before everything goes back to normal. (On a second thought, you could either wipe out homophobia for good or make it even worse because homosexuality suddenly becomes the "villains illness").

I think you would see the most drastical changes in the way families look. The number of long-term heterosexual relationships would be cut in half and the number of single-mothers would probably double. Depending on how well the social system supports single-mothers, there could be a steep decline in childbirth in the poorer population because single-moms simply cannot afford a second child.

The monogamous families with a heterosexual father, on the other hand, might have more children than is currently custom, just to make up for the many homosexual couples without children. Strictly religious Christians, Muslims and Jews would probably marry a woman and have children with her even if they became gay after the villainy finger snip. Formerly monogamous cultures could even adopt the custom of poloygamy, just to create a social security option for all women with a wish to give birth.

In the end, this development depends most on how the population of a land defines the value of raising a child. In China during the one-child policy the effect would have been minimal compared to other countries where women have 4 - 6 children in average.

Comment: You should add that'd there are hay transsexuals men who have had children, and transsexuals lesions who have gathered children. Obviously the transsexuals referenced hadn't fully transitioned

Answer (score 1):

It will likely not change the population in any significant way.

Heterosexuals will likely have more children; if half of those are homosexuals, then they will pitch in (even as adults, with income) and provide care.

I know several homosexuals that do this now. Being homosexual does not change the love homosexuals feel for family, parents, and children; or the responsibility they feel to care for their fellow humans.

In the past, humans have had widely varying numbers of children, from 1 (by law in China, slightly more due to law breaking) to 8 or 10 in countries where child death was common and your children were put to profitable work at the age of three; helping on the farm or ranch to earn income for their family.

What remains relatively constant is producing enough humans to replace the parents, plus about one. So, if approximately half of your children do not reproduce, then I'd expect the average couple to produce four or five children. Or, to be more fair, for the average heterosexual female to produce four or five children in her lifetime. Perhaps we'd develop political and financial incentives to help with this increase. Assess equal taxes on everybody (homosexuals and heterosexuals alike) but offer financial assistance and incentives to women for bearing children.

If not, the population would shrink, but that wouldn't be a terrible thing either. The primary reason we exploit the Earth is overpopulation, reducing the population (by natural attrition) by 90% would actually be a great boon to the planet. We could retain our current high energy and high tech usage and  have far more free natural resources for the remainder, allowing us to retire earlier, and remove much of the pressure of success that causes many women to postpone child-bearing to later in life, thus (currently) having fewer children. If they could be independent and not have to worry about that, they might quite naturally double their average number of children. Especially if they cohabit with homosexuals that help them raise the children, both in labor and finances. For example, a heterosexual couple might legally "marry" a homosexual couple and produce a larger family of five or six children for whom they all have equal legal financial responsibility of care and provision.

I suspect there would be large societal changes like that, and just not much impact on the population.

Comment: 2 considerations - 1) the mechanism of how exactly gays will be "pitching in" to provide child care may have profound effect on society. 2) "population shrinking" may be a one time effect, or it can be a continuous circle.

Comment: @Alexander I know some gays right now that already "pitch in", e.g. a regular schedule of babysitting for siblings, picking kids up from school, bringing them to extracurricular activities. I know one gay lawyer doing pretty well, thus far he has sent three kids through college, a nephew and two nieces, they finished on the "Uncle Gary" scholarship. Things work out, as I said, just because one is homosexual doesn't mean they don't love other people enough to help them out. If you are intimating something nefarious or sexual, I don't believe gays are any more prone to that than heterosexuals.

Comment: So, you are exemplifying an "extended family" model. May point is that any social model would work fine as long as all participants are in agreement with each other. But what if not?

Comment: @Alexander *but what if not?* Same as now, regardless of sexuality, many families have estranged members that want nothing to do with their birth family. I think that is a small minority. It is higher amongst homosexuals but I think that is a function of bigotry and prejudice against homosexuals by members of their birth families. In the OP's scenario, with 50% of people gay, I imagine that kind of prejudice dissipates fast, within a generation or two.

Comment: I am not talking about prejudice. Right now we have a relatively small, but important slice of population (regardless of sexuality) who want to "pitch in" via adoption. Being good uncles and aunts to their relatives' children is not good enough for them. Now we are looking forward to increasing this slice about tenfold.

Comment: @Alexander No, now you are just writing a story; you don't have any reason to believe being good uncles and aunts "is not good enough for them." Why not? The OP doesn't say their *psychology* has changed, so it will be the same social psychology of current homosexuals (likely 10% to 15% of the population if stigma is removed). They won't organize that much differently, or be suddenly driven to adoption, or anything else. They will pair up and help out **people they know** pretty much like they already do now in places where they aren't persecuted for being homosexuals.

Comment: This is just the fact - for many people, being good uncles and aunts is just not good enough (look at the adoption statistics). You are effectively arguing that human psychology will change, and most people will be Ok with not having their own children.

Comment: @Alexander I disagree. I am not interested in discussing this further, I don't think it is relevant to the question I am answering. As I already said, large societal changes may be in order, and what you are talking about is one of those; but I don't think the population would change enough to threaten the existence of humanity or anything like that. IMO the birth rate from heterosexuals would increase to compensate. Or gay women and men would procreate clinically as "friends" if they both want kids, with neither of them remotely promising sexual fidelity. But again, that is a societal change.